# Конструктор с параметрами в Spring

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, inversion-of-control, di

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно создавать бины через конструктор с параметрами.
Например, есть такой класс (два конструктора - пустой и с параметрами; геттеры, сеттеры для краткости не приводятся):

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Route {
    private LocalDateTime arrive;
    private LocalDateTime departure;
    private String from;
    private String to;

    public Route(){}

    public Route(LocalDateTime arrive, LocalDateTime departure, String from, String to) {
        this.arrive = arrive;
        this.departure = departure;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    // геттеры, сеттеры

    public void printRoute(){
        System.out.println("Откуда: " + from +
        ", куда: " + to +
        ", прибытие: " + arrive +
        ", отбытие: " + departure);
    }
}
```

Основной класс:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TrainScheduleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app-context.xml");
        Route route = ctx.getBean("routeEmpty", Route.class);
        route.printRoute();
    }
}
```

Файл "app-context.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans [url]http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd[/url]
        [url]http://www.springframework.org/schema/context[/url] http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

    <bean id="routeEmpty" class="com.example.demo.Route">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Собственно, вызывает затруднение следующее:

- как создавать маршруты (Route) с помощью конструктора с параметрами
  для типа `LocalDateTime`;
- как создавать разные маршруты (бины), передавая в конструктор
  необходимые параметры; то есть, чтобы параметры не прописывались в
  файле xml (тогда все маршруты создаются одинаковые), а можно было
  динамически передавать необходимые параметры из кода (аналог `Route route = new Route(arrive, departure, from, to)`).

Буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все классы, которые создаёт контекст Spring по умолчанию являются [Singletone](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), что подразумевает, что они создаются один раз в единственном экземпляре при старте приложения и живут до его завершения. Если вы хотите иметь множество Route, то этот вариант вам не подходит. Просто не включайте Route в конфигурацию Spring, а создавайте и используйте его, как обычный объект в Java. Либо используйте [scope](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes) prototype.

**Добавлено:**
Самое простое использовать Java конфигурацию (на аннотациях), а не XML

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    @Lazy(value = true)
    Route route(Date arrive, Date departure, String from, String to) {
        return new Route(arrive, departure, from, to);
    }
}
```

Получение экземпляра класса:

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Main2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ctx = 
           new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);

        Route route1 = (Route) ctx.getBean("route", new Date(), 
             new Date(), "Moscow", "London");
        route1.printRoute();

        Route route2 = (Route) ctx.getBean("route", new Date(), 
             new Date(), "Berlin", "Paris");
        route2.printRoute();

    }

}
```

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Route {
    private Date arrive;
    private Date departure;
    private String from;
    private String to;

    public Route(){}

    public Route(Date arrive, Date departure, String from, String to) {
        this.arrive = arrive;
        this.departure = departure;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    // геттеры, сеттеры

    public void printRoute(){
        System.out.println("Откуда: " + from +
        ", куда: " + to +
        ", прибытие: " + arrive +
        ", отбытие: " + departure);
    }
}
```

**Пример с XML конфигурацией (проверено - точно работает)**

файл application-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
    <bean id="hello" class="Hello" scope="prototype">
        <constructor-arg value="0"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

файл Hello.java

```
public class Hello {
    private int count;
    public Hello(int param) {
       count = param;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(count);
    }
}
```

Файл Main.java

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
```

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = 
           new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-config.xml");
        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            Hello hello = (Hello) context.getBean("hello", x);
            System.out.println(hello.toString());
        }
     }
 }

Comment: Собственно, пусть будет prototype. Разумеется, я могу вообще без Spring обойтись, но зачем-то он нужен, раз его требуют везде, куда не плюнь. Пока не могу разобраться, как создавать группу бинов с разными свойствами. Большинство примеров в интернете (все, сколько я ни смотрел) передают значение параметра через value. Не могу же я в xml записать заранее значение, которое будет формироваться динамически и будет известно только в runtime.

Comment: @woodhead можно использовать Java-конфигурацию и подставлять параметры так, как вам захочется :)

Comment: Alex Chermenin, не уверен, что я вас понял. Можете привести пример Java-конфигурации?

Comment: Добавил примеры в ответ. Примеры брал из головы, сразу может и не заработать. В случае чего надо уточнить синтаксис в документации Spring.

Comment: @Igor Kudryashov почему-то не работает `@autowired`. Кстати, название класса `Configuration` пришлось сменить на `ConfigRoute`, а то компилятор ругался на одинаковые имена аннотации и класса. Вместо `exampleMetod` прописал обычный `main`, и в нём инициализировал все переменные, используемые в качестве параметров. Во всех классах сделал нужные импорты. Пока не понял, в чём причина ошибки (почему-то не работает автосвязывание).

Comment: Добавил пример с XML конфигурацией. Проверил у себя - точно работает.

Comment: Исправил пример с аннотацией, тоже проверил - тоже работает.

Comment: @Igor Kudryashov, у меня пример с аннотацией заработал только после того, как в вашем примере в классе `Config` вместо `@Bean` поставил `@Bean(name="route")`. Иначе выдавало ошибку     `Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'route' available`

Comment: Версии Spring наверное у нас разные, может быть из-за этого...

Comment: @IgorKudryashov  в maven указано **groupId** - `org.springframework.boot`, **artifactId** - `spring-boot-starter-parent`, **version** - `1.5.4.RELEASE`.

Answer (score 1):

Я не находил информацию, как передавать в конструктор бина динамические параметры. Как правило, параметры передаются через xml или property-файлы.

В Вашем случае вариант может быть такой: создавать **Prototype**-бины обычным способом (без конструктора), а необходимые **private** поля после создания бина задавать с помощью сеттеров, тогда каждый бин будет иметь свою уникальную конфигурацию.

Comment: Да вот тоже пришел к такому же выводу. Но мне показалось, что я чего-то недоглядел. Есть ещё мысль использовать: `init-method`, интерфейс `InitializingBean` или аннотацию `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: Для динамического изменения параметров можно использовать либо Groovy либо MBeans. Использовать scope prototype не совсем хорошее решение проблемы (поскольку обычно бины инжектятся в другие бины и как только вы  заинжектите бин со scope prototype в бин singlton ваше решение перестанет действовать).